# python aiohttp Request a lot of URLs Blocked question

Tags: python, aiohttp

I am reading a 40MB (1 million lines) url and accessing them to find a character on the page. When I visited, I found that the request would always be paused, or blocked,Can't figure out what to wait for? Waiting for a response from the request? 
The code is a concurrent application found on github and then modified by itself. Can you help me see where the problem is? Thank you~

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# encoding: utf-8
# time : 2019/6/1 20:31

import asyncio
from itertools import islice

import aiofiles as aiofiles
from aiohttp import ClientSession

try:
    import uvloop

    asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(uvloop.EventLoopPolicy())
except ImportError:
    pass
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36",
}


def iter_list():
    all_url = []
    with open("Domain_list.txt") as input_file:
        for line in islice(input_file, 0, None):
            all_url.append(line.strip())

        return all_url


async def save_txt(url):
    async with aiofiles.open('ok.txt', 'a+') as f:
        await f.write(url + '\n')


async def fetch(item, session):
    try:
        async with session.post(url=item, headers=headers, timeout=None) as req:
             """
                Find character '<<<EOT' And save
            """
            code = '<<<EOT'
            html = await req.text()
            if req.status in [200, 201]:
                if html.find(code) > 2:
                    await save_txt(item)
                    await print(item, html.find(code))
                else:
                    await print(f'{item}not!')
            else:
                await print(f'{item},{req.status()}')

    except:
        pass


async def bound_fetch(sem, url, session):
    # Getter function with semaphore.
    async with sem:
        await fetch(url, session)


async def run(lists):
    tasks = []
    # create instance of Semaphore
    sem = asyncio.Semaphore(500)

    # Create client session that will ensure we dont open new connection
    # per each request.
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        for i in lists:
            # pass Semaphore and session to every GET request
            task = asyncio.ensure_future(bound_fetch(sem, i, session))
            tasks.append(task)

        responses = asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        await responses


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
lists = iter_list()
future = asyncio.ensure_future(run(lists))
loop.run_until_complete(future)
```

Comment: What do you mean by `the request would always be paused, or blocked`? Is your script not sending the requests, or are the responses failing? Because standard APIs have rate limits on their end.

Comment: The request has been sent, I am thinking of waiting for the address response

Comment: I am guessing here, but I've had a similar issue with blocking in `text()` when content encoding is not provided via the `Content-Type` header in the response (e.g. `text/html; charset=utf-8`), in which case _aiohttp_ would [try to detect](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/blob/f6f647eb828fa738610d61481f11fa51e42599e9/aiohttp/client_reqrep.py#L995) the encoding from the body using `chardet`, which can very slow. If that is the case here as well, you could try installing `cchardet` to speed it up, pass (force) an encoding to `text()` or use the binary response from `read()` (if applicable).

Comment: I have read the text() question on github and said it has been fixed。However, I have tested read() later, it is really smooth, but it will still block.

Comment: Finally, I optimized the way to read txt (to avoid reading errors), and some settings, after which I successfully ran 1 million urls.         Probably so, I hope to help you.                                                   
        import async_timeout  
        with async_timeout.timeout(20):
            async with session.get(url=item, headers=headers) as req:
                source = await req.text()